# "Maximize the chances of searchability" or "maximize searchability"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

Someone edited my [question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/38686/why-are-voiceless-plosives-p-t-k-unaspirated-after-s) on Linguistics SE and said in edit summary:

> gave more general title to make it easy to find on the web

I wonder how I could rephrase the above sentence. I rephrased it as:

> 1. Gave a more general title to **maximize/ increase the chances of searchability**
> 2. Gave a more general title to **make it more searchable**

Is this something a native speaker would say? Do "maximize the chances" and "searchability" go together?

or should it just be:

> ... **maximize searchability**

?

I'm asking this because I've never come across a sentence like this before and [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22maximize%20the%20chances%20of%20searchability%22&rlz=1C1CHBD_enPK937PK937&oq=%22maximize%20the%20chances%20of%20searchability%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.7999j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) this shows no results of "maximize the chances of searchability". (I would also appreciate if you suggested another alternative so long it's not off-topic.)

Comment: To a first approximation, ***searchability*** here (underlined in red as "not a word" by my browser) is a "neologism* that could just as well have been coined as [***googleability*** or ***googlability***.](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/buzzword/entries/googleable.html#:~:text=googleability%20or%20googlability,search%20engine%2C%20especially%20Google%C2%AE) And - Surprise, surprise! - after writing that sentence, I discover that MW dictionary does in fact list both spellings of that latter coinage. The words "the chances of" are completely redundant here, though.

Comment: I agree with FumbleFingers; "The chances of searchability" is redundant and wordy, because *searchability* already means something like "the capacity or capability of being searched for", so "the chances of the capacity of being searched for" is overly wordy at best.